# GIT shows changed file, but it does not exist in repo, only local

Tags: git

I have files under `.idea/' directory in my project.

I accidentally commited it, and sent to the repo. Then made a fix to remove it from the repo but not locally, but GIT seems to still be tracking it in my local clone.

How can I update my repo without recloning and without making a new commit (because officially it does not exist)?

Comment: Does `git rm <filename>` do what you would like it to? (or adding `.idea/` to your `.gitignore`?)

Comment: `from the repo but not locally` ... Usually the problem is opposite, namely you've removed it locally but not from the repo.  How did you "remove" it from the repo?